# Colocar ponteiro na segunda linha para escrever?

Tags: php, arquivo

Escrevendo um texto no arquivo

```
    $fn = fopen('teste.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fn, '-meu texto aqui');
    fclose($fn);
```

Lendo a segunda linha do arquivo

```
    $fn = "teste.txt";
    $nr_linha = 1;
    $f_contents = file ($fn);
    @$sua_linha = $f_contents [$nr_linha];
    print $sua_linha;
```

Como posso modificar a primeira parte do código para gravar somente na segunda linha?
Tentei isso sem sucesso!

```
    $fn = fopen('teste.txt', 'a');
    @$fc = file ($fn);
    @$fn = $fc [1];
    fwrite($fn, '-alteração na segunda linha');
    fclose($fn);
```

Comment: Você sabe o tamanho da primeira linha ou ele é determinado perlo terminador de linha?

Comment: O tamanho da primeira linha é fixo apenas duas letras sendo elas "<?".

Comment: Eu percebi que neste caso será irrelevante já as demais podem variar, então é melhor escrever o arquivo todo novamente.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro erro é usar o modo de *append*. Você quer [escrever no arquivo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) e não adicionar algo ao fim do arquivo.

A outra coisa é que precisa achar onde a primeira linha termina e começar escrever logo depois. Tem várias maneiras de fazer isto. Uma delas que é mais simples é escrever novamente a primeira linha após lê-la. Acho que você tentou fazer mas na verdade jogou o conteúdo da primeira linha em cima do manipulador do arquivo, ou seja, você perdeu a conexão com o arquivo.

Na verdade tem um outro problema. A segunda linha pode ser maior ou menor que o conteúdo original, então seria melhor escrever novamente tudo o que vem depois.

```
$fn = fopen('teste.txt', 'w'); //note que isto destrói o conteúdo do arquivo
$fc = file($fn);
$fc[1] = '-alteração na segunda linha';
file_put_contents($fn, $fc);
fclose($fn);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/ResetFile.php).

Eu mantive os nomes da variáveis para não te confundir mas não sei se não forma justamente elas que te confundiram. Dar nomes significativos para as variáveis ajudam muito entender o código.

Por fim não tente acessar o arquivo concorrentemente já que não há controle de travamento neste algoritmo.

Answer (score -1):

É só fazer dessa forma:

```
<?php

//Lê o arquivo
$linhas = explode("\n", file_get_contents("./arquivo.txt"));

//Lê somente o conteúdo da linha [1] do array ou seja linha 2 do texto
$linha_n = $linhas[1];

//Abre o arquivo colocando o ponteiro de escrita no final
$arquivo = fopen('arquivo.txt','r+');
      if ($arquivo) {
while(true) {
$linha = fgets($arquivo);
if ($linha==null) break;

//Busca o conteúdo que vai ser alterado
if(preg_match("/$linha_n/", $linha)) {
//este é o lugar onde vai trocar a palavra
$string .= str_replace("$linha_n", "novo texto para linha", $linha);
} else {
//Vai colocando tudo numa nova string
$string.= $linha;
}
}
//Move o ponteiro para o início
rewind($arquivo);

//Apaga todo o conteúdo
ftruncate($arquivo, 0);

//Reescreve conteúdo do arquivo
if (!fwrite($arquivo, $string)) die('Não foi possível atualizar');
echo 'Arquivo atualizado';
fclose($arquivo);
}
?>
```